# Dynamically update canvasOverlay property of jQuery jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I want to dynamically update canvasOverlay property of jQuery jqPlot. This will provide the effect of a timeline in my jqPlot. This effect should be similar to the one shown in this [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QA8r/93/). However, instead of drawing points, I want to update `canvasOverlay` property every second:

```
                canvasOverlay: {
                    show: true,
                    objects: [
                        { rectangle: { xmax: new Date(), xminOffset: "0px", xmaxOffset: "0px", yminOffset: "0px", ymaxOffset: "0px",
                                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", showTooltip: true } },
                    ]
                }
```

How can I do this? What are the functions I should use?

UPDATE:

My idea is to do something like this:

```
                    canvasOverlay: {
                        name: 'current',
                        show: true,
                        objects: [
                            { rectangle: { xmax: new Date(), xminOffset: "0px", xmaxOffset: "0px", yminOffset: "0px", ymaxOffset: "0px",
                                                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", showTooltip: true } },
                        ]
                    } 

/...

var co = plot.plugins.canvasOverlay;
var current = co.get('current');

current.options.objects.rectangle.xmax = new Date();
co.draw(plot);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Hope it might be useful for someone:

```
canvasOverlay: {
                        show: true,
                        objects: [
                            { 
                                rectangle: { 
                                    name: 'current',
                                    xmax: new Date(), 
                                    xminOffset: "0px", 
                                    xmaxOffset: "0px", 
                                    yminOffset: "0px", 
                                    ymaxOffset: "0px",
                                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", 
                                    showTooltip: true 
                                } 
                            },
                 ]
             } 

                $('#buttonNext').bind("click", function() {
                    counter++;
                    UpdateTimeline(plot1);
                });

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#buttonNext').click();
                });

                window.setInterval(function(){
                    $('#buttonNext').click();
                }, 1000);

function UpdateTimeline(plot1) {
                    var co = plot1.plugins.canvasOverlay;
                    co.get("current").options.xmax = new Date();
                    co.draw(plot1);
                    plot1.replot();                 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but also needed to be able to add additional overlays dynamically (not just modify existing).

I used the following method to redraw the chart with a new/modified array of overlay objects:

```
var chart = $.jqplot(...);
var overlayObjects = getOtherOverlayObjects();
chart.plugins.canvasOverlay = new $.jqplot.CanvasOverlay({
    show: true,
    objects: overlayObjects
});
chart.replot();
```

The parameters passed to the $.jqplot.CanvasOverlay() function have the same structure as the canvasOverlay-options that are initially passed to $.jqplot().